# Qual é a origem de «Tiago» e «Thiago»?

Tags: etimologia, nomes

O nome *Tiago* tornou-se popular em Portugal para aí há uns trinta anos. Entretanto tenho encontrado também a variante *Thiago* em brasileiros. E a minha primeira questão é acerca da origem deste ***h***.

O meu nome já se escreveu *Jacintho*, no tempo em que se escrevia *hypothese, hypotheca* e *pharmacia*. Mas segundo julgo saber, o nome *Tiago* surgiu duma confusão: o homem era Santo Iago, e mais tarde o pessoal pensou que fosse São Tiago. Então donde veio o ***h*** de *Thiago*? Haveria também a variante Hiago?

Depois há a questão de quando é que estes nomes surgiram. Creio que *Diogo* é uma variante de *Tiago* e é um nome antigo. Sem me esforçar muito consigo pensar no [Diogo Cão (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogo_C%C3%A3o) do século XV. Mas não me lembro de nenhum Tiago ou Thiago na história portuguesa ou brasileira.

Portanto a minha pergunta é: **como se formaram e quando é que surgiram na língua portuguesa as variantes *Tiago* e *Thiago?***

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiago,_o_Justo

Comment: @JorgeB. Nem me tinha lembrado dos santos. Resta saber se a grafia antiga era *Thiago*, como *Jacintho*.

Comment: @JorgeB. qual é parte do artigo que devia olhar? Não estou a encontrar nada lá sobre a mudança de Iάκωβος/Iacobus para "Tiago". [Neste outro artigo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiago_(nome)) sim, e [aqui também](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iago_(nome)), mas com poucas fontes.

Comment: @DanGetz o artigo era só para dar a ideia que já existe há milhares de anos.

Comment: @JorgeB. mas precisamente isto que não encontrei lá, visto que o artigo fala sobre uma pessoa que não foi conhecido como "Tiago" no seu tempo, só depois—e este depois foi quando?

Comment: A mim parece que "Thiago" é inovação, do mesmo gênero, senão da mesma qualidade, que "Fellype" ou "Gysela"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ao que parece, segundo o [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiago_(nome)) e as fontes citadas lá, tens alguma razão, (ênfase minha)

> Tiago é, na verdade, uma corruptela da outra versão portuguesa de
>   Ya'acov que é Iago. O nome Tiago surgiu da aglutinação de dois
>   elementos **Santo** e **Iago** que produziu **Santiago**. Por sua vez, ao se
>   separar novamente a palavra Santo, surgiu uma corruptela que depois
>   viria a se tornar o nome Tiago

Na verdade, é fácil de perceber que pela sonoridade de Santiago (São Tiago) parece que esta teoria tem lógica. Pelo que diz numa das fontes terá tido influência no espanhol.

Segundo [este site espanhol](http://www.sellamara.com/nombre/tiago) a história corrobora-se,

> Por un error de analogía (los nombres se transmitían de manera oral y
>   eso daba lugar a errores) se interpretó Santiago como San+Tiago, en
>   lugar de Sant+Iago que es como era en realidad.

Ou seja, por um erro de interpretação oral Sant Iago acabou por se transformar em «San Tiago» e «Sam Tiago» ou como conhecemos agora «São Tiago».

---

Já no caso de Thiago, e também segundo o [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiago_(nome)), ao que parece é derivado de um erro de etimologia,

> Thiago, derivada de uma falsa etimologia que atribuía sem qualquer
>   fundamento o th de uma suposta origem grega iniciada com a letra θ.

Mas não consegui verificar a fonte desta última afirmação que pela indicação estará [neste livro](https://books.google.pt/books?redir_esc=y&hl=pt-PT&id=_uwuAAAAYAAJ&dq=CASTRO%2C%20Marcos%20de.%20A%20imprensa%20e%20o%20caos%20na%20ortografia.%20Rio%20de%20Janeiro&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Thiago).

*Por curiosidade:*

> La evolución completa sería algo así: Iago> Sant Iago> Santiago> Tiago
>   y en castellano, finalmente, Diago/Diego.

---

Quanto ao surgimento, a primeira referência que encontrei de «Tiago» no google books foi de 1600, [Historia da vida do padre Francisco de Xavier](https://books.google.pt/books?id=xpboetFBU5cC&pg=PA177&dq=%22tiago%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tiago%22&f=false):

[image]

Já no CIPM - Corpus encontrei uma referência bem mais antiga do século XIV, na «Narrativa de livro de linhagens» em que encontramos a expressão «Sam Tiago». Encontrei também referências do século XIV tanto de Diego como de Diogo e Diago, sendo que este último só em texto em Espanhol ou a falar de alguém Espanhol. Até ao que se pode apurar todos eles já existiam neste século.

No caso de «Thiago» encontrei [um livro de 1679](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qQXvsmPgAlcC&pg=PA748&dq=%22Thiago%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqsJ-ForzRAhWK1hQKHSiRBZEQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Thiago%22&f=false) que pode, ou não, querer dizer alguma coisa, pelo menos quer dizer que esta variante já existia nessa altura. Encontrei também uma referência de «Thiago» de 1888 no livro «Cartas a Emília» de Ramalho Ortigao no Corpus do Português. No Google encontrei também em 1870 «História do Teatro Português» de Teófilo Braga onde usa e abusa de «Thiago». Estas referências todas quererão dizer que já se usava Thiago nessa altura. Há, inclusive, mais de 20 autores que usam esta forma com «h» incluindo a [Academia de Ciências de Lisboa](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3CNMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA145&dq=Thiago&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY65b-_sjRAhUBaRQKHdMFAoY4lgEQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=Thiago&f=false) e até mesmo Bocage. O curioso é que acontece exatamente [o mesmo](https://books.google.pt/books?id=GVdZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA240&dq=Tiago&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVwtbB_8jRAhXDWxQKHewSC4o4ggEQ6AEIQzAH#v=onepage&q=Tiago&f=false) relativamente a «Tiago».

É de notar que tanto «Tiago» como «Thiago», nestas fontes acima citadas, aparecem sempre como referência a «São Tiago», pelo menos até ao inicio do século XX.

Por volta do inicio do século XX «Tiago» e «Thiago» para além do nome do Santo também começaram a ser usados como nome próprio. Em 1930, no Brasil, «Tiago» tinha uma frequência de cerca de 279 pessoas e «Thiago» 109, mas na década de 1980 ambos tiveram uma subida exponencial de utilização como podem ver nos gráficos:

[image]
[image]

Já em Portugal aconteceu a mesma explosão do nome «Tiago» mas nenhuma ocorrência de «Thiago».

Comment: És capaz de encontrar material mais antigo no [Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/); registo obrigatório mas gratuito. E tens também o [Corpus do Português](http://corpus.byu.edu/).

Comment: Não viste bem o *Diago*. No CIPM há vários textos em galaico-português (creio que todos são) que mencionam *Diago*. Há um Diago Lopiz, tenente de Lamego (chancelaria do rei Afonso III de Portugal, 1278); e um Diago Diaz mencionado em 1296 num documento de Pinhel.

Comment: Os gráficos de nomes por data de nascimento foram gerados com que dados?